# why ajax call not succeed?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I create this ajax function:

```
function getAssociatedProperties(callback, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/LayerProperty/get',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 5,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: callback,
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

And here is my web api class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace GeomindMobile.Controllers
{
    public class LayerProperty : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever ajax function fired I get this error:

```
http://localhost/LayerProperty/get 404 (Not Found)
```

**Update**

```
Here is my RouteConfig:

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

What is wrong with my code?why ajax call not succeed?

Comment: You should just pass api/LayerProperty/5 not api/LayerProperty/Get/5

Comment: `crossDomain: true` why are you using this? Do you need to simulate a crossDomain request on the same domain? Because that's what this setting does.

Comment: Could you post your routing configuration also?

Comment: @juunas see upadte please

Comment: I think that is your Route for MVC not WEB API... try post the web api one instead...

Comment: @Milneyyes it's MVC route

Answer (score 2):

```
function getAssociatedProperties(callback, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/LayerProperty', // <--- You do not need the 'get' here, but you do need the /api/
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 5,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: callback,
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Milney,thanks for post. But when I use your example I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your method with below piece of code ?

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> get()
{
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller name with your controller then it will fire from ajax request, currently you're not using the right naming convention in mvc.

Your's

```
public class LayerProperty : ApiController
```

Mine

```
public class LayerPropertyController : ApiController
```

Answer (score -1):

you have error in url.

```
function getAssociatedProperties(callback, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/LayerProperty/get',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 5,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: callback,
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}
```